# how to reshape xtrain array and what about input shape?

Tags: python, keras

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.layers import Activation,Dense,Convolution2D
from keras.models import save_model,load_model,Sequential
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

(xtrain,ytrain),(xtest,ytest)=mnist.load_data()
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32,3,activation='relu',input_shape=(60000,28,28)))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              <space>metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, epochs=10, batch_size=60000)
```

Comment: Hi Adnane, welcome to AI stackexchange, could you please give more informations about your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keras requires you to set the input_shape of the network. This is the shape of a single instance of your data which would be `(28,28)`. However, Keras also needs a channel dimension thus the input shape for the MNIST dataset would be `(28,28,1)`.

---

First we load the data as you did,

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

print('Training data shape: ', x_train.shape)
print('Testing data shape : ', x_test.shape)
```

> Training data shape:  (60000, 28, 28) 
>   Testing data shape :  (10000, 28, 28)

Then we reshape the examples in the MNIST dataset to have the additional channel dimension

```
# Input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# Channels go last for TensorFlow backend
x_train_reshaped = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
x_test_reshaped = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)
```

And now we can define our model as you did. Do note the necessary Flatten layer between the Convolutional layers and the Dense layer.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, epochs=10, batch_size=60000)
```